# NavigationController becomes nil after present a modal

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In my project, I'm using a modal to show a detail of a service with a button to confirm a navigation to this service. In all my screens, I have the following example code to navigate throug screens:

`code #1`

```swift
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([servicesVC], animated: false)
```

or

`code #2`

```swift
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(servicesVC, animated: false)
```

and everything runs fine.

Then I present my CustomViewController as a modal using the following code:

```swift
self.navigationController?.present(serviceDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But if I try to navigate to another screen from my modal (`serviceDetailVC`) using the `code #1` or `#2`, my `navigationController` becomes `nil` and I can do nothing.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If A is your screen that presents the details as a modal B, are you popping B when you're done or directly trying to push another screen to your navigation stack?

Comment: @HarshvardhanArora I tried `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` on modal B before navigation but results are the same

Answer (score 3):

You're presenting modally ViewController that is not embedded in UINavigationController.

Instead of:

```
navigationController?.present(serviceDetailVC, animated: true)
```

You should do something like this:

```
let detailNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: serviceDetailVC)
navigationController?.present(detailNC, animated: true)
```

This way, you'll be able to push/set other view controllers to your modal screen.

Comment: Ok but, how can I push viewcontrollers FROM my modal? This didn't work.

Comment: Oh man, I just had the same problem and this answer saved me hours

Answer (score -2):

use

```
self.present(serviceDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

instead of

```
self.navigationController?.present(serviceDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried this before. Didn't work.

Comment: Instead of using this self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([servicesVC], animated: false) use self.dismiss(animated: true) on modal presented